# How to generate alt attributes with php / filters?

Tags: images, filters, seo

I would like to generate to generate some kind of automatic `alt` attributes for the images, if they don't have `alt` set up.

Found this code, but it doesn't work for some reason:

```
function add_alt_tags($content)
{
    global $post;
    preg_match_all('/<img (.*?)\/>/', $content, $images);
    if(!is_null($images))
    {
        foreach($images[1] as $index => $value)
        {
            if(!preg_match('/alt=/', $value))
            {
                $new_img = str_replace('<img', '<img alt="'.$post->post_title.'"', $images[0][$index]);
                $content = str_replace($images[0][$index], $new_img, $content);
            }
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_alt_tags', 99999);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best solution, but did it like this:

```
function add_alt_tags($content)
{
    global $post;
    $content = str_replace('alt=""', 'alt="'.$post->post_title .'"',
    $content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_alt_tags', 100);
```